# PHP -> JavaScript RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm very stumped here. I'm trying to take some server-side PHP and introduce some JavaScript that does the same thing - giving hints to the user as they type. I have the following, which is attempting to find all lowercase letters, uppercase letters, and numbers 0 or more times; it then deletes those characters, leaving behind a string containing everything else. I then take the length of this and compare it to a variable maxSymbols, which is 5.

I cannot get this to evaluate properly... what am I missing here?

```
else if(passwordValue.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9])*/, '').length > maxSymbols){

// Check the maximum number of symbols in the password.
    document.getElementById("passwordHint").innerHTML = "You've used too many symbols, " + maxSymbols + " is the maximum.";
    document.getElementById("passwordHint").style.color = "red";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `g` modifier for your regular expression. Without the `g`, you are only replacing the first match.

Try `if(passwordValue.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9])*/g, '').length > maxSymbols)`.

Hope this helps,

Pete

Comment: Both answers work great, thanks guys/gals. This just proves that I have much to learn about regex syntax between languages.

Comment: Are these flags unique to JavaScript? It's interesting that my PHP regex works as I intended without the 'g' flag.

Comment: @patrickn js does have it's own flavor of js.  I don't know how close it is to PHP's but they are going to have differences.

Answer (score 0):

```
.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9])*/, '')
```

should be

```
.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')
```

and you should be good. :)  What your are searching for in the first one is 0 or more of those characters together.  What you need is that character class replaces globally (the g).

Comment: Interesting, both pages I am using as a reference don't show the /g flag. Unless I'm missing it.

Comment: http://www.learn-javascript-tutorial.com/RegularExpressions.cfm
http://www.regextester.com/jssyntax.html